# Xamarin shared code between iOS, Android and Core project

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and made two interfaces for Android and iOS.
I have one Core project and put references in the Android and iOS project to the Core project.

How can I use code from my Core project in my iOS/Android project?

For example, this is my Core class TestClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FindMyRide.Core
{
    public class TestClass
    {

        public string TestString { get; set; }

        public TestClass ()
        {
            TestString = "Hallo";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I display the TestString in my iOS or Android application?

I don't know if this is the correct use of shared coding in Xamarin, as I said I'm very new to this and to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either [build a PCL](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) or build platform specific libraries with [code sharing](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/).